# Set the caption for each image in a group just before opening the Fancybox popup window?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use fancybox2. The following is html:

```
<a rel="example_group" class="fancybox" title="Custom title 1" data-caption="caption-1-with-html" href="full_path_to_image.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="path_to_image_thumbs.jpg">
</a>
<a rel="example_group" class="fancybox"  title="Custom title 2" data-caption="caption-2-with-html" href="full_path_to_image.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="path_to_image_thumbs.jpg">
</a>
```

Title attribute is for mouse-hover event in browsers so that no one sees html tags. When someone clicks on any of thumbnail images, fancybox opens a popup window and data-caption attribute should be used for the caption shown in it.

How can I handle this situation with fancybox? I tried many things but none of them worked. The following is one thing I tried:

```
   $(".fancybox")
        .fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            nextEffect: 'none',
            prevEffect: 'none',
            padding: [0, 0, 20, 0],
            margin: [20, 60, 20, 60],
        helpers : {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        },
        beforeLoad: function() {
            var box = this;
            $(".fancybox").each(function(index, item) {
                var text = $(this).attr('data-caption');
                box.title = text;
            });
        }
});
```

But this script sets the same caption (caption-2-with-html) for both images. Here is the JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/ahLLcktx/8/

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that the `.each()` method always returns the last element of the iteration, hence the same caption on any image.

The solution should be simpler, just get the caption from the current element like :

```
beforeLoad: function() {
    this.title = $(this.element).attr('data-caption');
}
```

See your forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ahLLcktx/9/)**

... or better :

```
beforeLoad: function() {
    this.title = $(this.element).data('caption');
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ahLLcktx/10/)**

Comment: Works beautifully. Especially like $(this.element).data('caption', which not only solves the problem, but also teaches data(). Thanks!!!!!!